# How can I go about downloading a package in a lambda during runtime. I am trying to use the module geopandas which is too large for a layer

Tags: python, aws-lambda, pip

I am currently trying to pip install the package during runtime to a tmp folder but getting the following error:

```
Importing the numpy C-extensions failed.
```

I have tried downloading the package from s3 during runtime and then get an error, {no module geopandas{. I have already tried adding the `pythonpath=/tmp` env variable. I am trying to avoid using a docker container for this particular project.